# In Laua in Roblox Studio what does call mean?

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I am trying to go through the tutorials to learn how to make a game in Roblox.  I am at the part in the website: Guides, Tutorials, Environments, In-Game sounds.  Then all the way at the bottom of the page where is says Play a sound.  Here is what it says:

Create a variable for SoundService, then another variable to store the feedback sound.

```
local pickupObjects = game.Workspace.Collectables.Objects
local objectsArray = pickupObjects:GetChildren()

local SoundService = game:GetService("SoundService")
local feedbackSound = SoundService:FindFirstChild("FeedbackSound")

local function partTouched(otherPart, objectPart)
```

Then the next part says:

To play the chime, find the function partTouched. Within the if statement, call feedbackSound:Play() to play the sound.

```
local function partTouched(otherPart, objectPart)
    local whichCharacter = otherPart.Parent
    local humanoid = whichCharacter:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")

    -- Play the sound, once finished, destroy the object
    if humanoid and objectPart.CanCollide == true then
        feedbackSound:Play()
    end
end
```

I do not know what it means by create a variable it didn't give me one what am I suppose to type and where?
The next part I do not know what it means by call feedbackSound:Play(), what does call mean, what am I suppose to do?

In StarterPlayer > StarterPlayerScripts, create a new local script named CollectableSounds.

The code below will run the partTouched function whenever the player touches a collectable. Copy the code into your script.

Then this is the script they give to put in:

```
local pickupObjects = game.Workspace.Collectables.Objects
local objectsArray = pickupObjects:GetChildren()

local function partTouched(otherPart, objectPart)
    local whichCharacter = otherPart.Parent
    local humanoid = whichCharacter:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")

    if humanoid and objectPart.CanCollide == true then

    end
end

-- Binds every object part to the touch function so it works on all parts
for objectIndex = 1, #objectsArray do
    local objectPart = objectsArray[objectIndex]
    objectPart.Touched:Connect(function(otherPart)
        partTouched(otherPart, objectPart)
    end)
end
```

I put:

```
local SoundService = game:GetService("SoundService")
local feedbackSound = SoundService:FindFirstChild("FeedbackSound")
```

in between lines 2 and 4 of the larger script

then I put:

```
feedbackSound:Play()
```

on line 9 of the larger script

I tried playing the test game and no sound when walking into the green gems.  I noticed the feedbackSound:Play() has nothing inside the parentheses so I tried putting the sound ID in it rbxassetid://4110925712 with and without parentheses.  I tried putting FeedbackSound inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

First off, to answer the problem in the name of the question, "calling" a function means to "run" it:

```lua
function ExampleFunction(Value) -- "define" the function
    local NewValue = Value + 10
    print(tostring(Value) .. " plus 10 is " .. tostring(NewValue))
end

ExampleFunction(5) -- "call" the function
```

In this example, I:

- Define a function called "ExampleFunction" that takes a value, and tells you what that value plus 10 is.
- Inside the parentheses, I write a variable name "Value" (and of course, I can add more if I want, separated by commas), these are formally known as *"parameters"*. Those are the names of the values the function "takes in".
- On the last line, I run that function by providing it's name, followed by parentheses. **This is known as *"calling"* the function**.
- Inside the parentheses, I put a value that the function will take in (again, I can put more, separated by commas), formally known as the *"arguments"*.

---

In Roblox, many types of data store functions inside of them. Let's take a look at FindFirstChild for example, since it seems to be at the center of your problem:

`InstanceA:FindFirstChild("InstanceB")`

This line will search InstanceA for an instance named "InstanceB", if no such instance exists, then this will *"return"* a value known as *nil*, Luau's way of representing nothing. This value can then be stored in a variable, as you do:

`local feedbackSound = SoundService:FindFirstChild("FeedbackSound")`

This line will search the SoundService instance for an instance called "FeedbackSound". It is very important that this Sound instance actually exists inside of SoundService, because you treat it like it does later in the script.

Now, I don't have access to your place, so I can only assume that your problem is either:

- The Sound instance *doesn't* exist inside of SoundService, in which case, you need to actually insert a sound into the SoundService, name it "FeedbackSound", and set it's SoundId property, so that it has an actual sound to play. This will cause *FindFirstChild* to return nil, causing problems later.
- The Sound instance *does* exist inside of SoundService, *but it's SoundId property isn't set* to `rbxassetid://4110925712`. If a Sound's SoundId isn't set, playing it will cause nothing to happen.

This should hopefully fix your problem :D

---

Here are some extra nitpicks you might wanna take into consideration:

- The `:Play()` function does not take a sound ID, in fact, no values go into the parentheses. So that line is actually fine the way it was. (You will get an error if you put anything in the parentheses)
- It is a common beginner mistake to write "`== true`" when writing `if` statements, heck, I used to do it too! However, it's completely unnecessary. All it will do is compare the value of `CanCollide` to `true`, and result in `true` if it's `true`, which is redundant.